# parsing some code for url

Tags: parsing, web-scraping

I have to extract some code of the web page: **http://www.bebesymas.com/edades/bebes-de-menos-de-6-meses/bebe-de-4-meses* The problem that I have is what I would like to extract is when I click on the icon "Leer Mas". With Firebug I see that it seems that it executes some Ajax code. How could I extract the correct URL to can extract what I want. Many thanks and sorry for my English

Comment: It would be nice if you upvoted+accepted my answer if it helped :)

Comment: Sorry I dont have reputation to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the `NET` tab in Firebug, you will see that when clicking the link it fetches this URL:

`http://www.bebesymas.com/json/productdesc/20351/27211`

Now if you search the HTML for `27211` you will find this:

[image]

So you just need to grab the productid and the postid from those two elements and then construct the URL like so:

`http://www.bebesymas.com/json/productdesc/`**productid**`/`**postid**

Comment: Many thanks! A question, how do you see that when you click on the link it gives you the url:http://www.bebesymas.com/json/productdesc/20351/27211. With firebug, If I set the mouse in the link "Leer Mas" it gives me: <div class="read-more">
<a class="moredesc" rel="nofollow" href="#" style="display: inline;">Leer más</a>
</div>

Comment: You want to use the `NET` tab in Firebug. That will show you all the requests and responses that are made.